# java Connection Pooling from Oracle

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to make a connection pool following this link: 
http://192.9.162.55/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/conpool.html

I don't understand something:
Somewhere in the **class JDCConnectionDriver implements Driver** you can find this method:

```
public static final String URL_PREFIX = "jdbc:jdc:";
public Connection connect(String url, Properties props) 
                                   throws SQLException {
    if(!url.startsWith(URL_PREFIX) {
         return null;
    }
    return pool.getConnection();
}
```

so, if you use mysql (for example), the url it will always start with **jdbc**... so the method connect it will never return you a connection...
Why is that?

Also I would like to ask you which is the best connection pooling framework...

Comment: c3p0 is a good connection pooling framework as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so, if you use mysql (for example),
>   the url it will always start with
>   jdbc... so the method connect it will
>   never return you a connection... Why
>   is that?

This driver is specifically written to connect to a JDC Connection. That's why. It's looking for a url starting with `jdbc:jdc:` and not just `jdbc:`.

> Also I would like to ask you which is
>   the best connection pooling
>   framework...

The most well known Connection Pooling library out there and used on many application servers and servlet containers is [Apache Object Pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/). The most common connection pooling is [Apache DBCP (DataBase Connection Pooling)](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/).

Also, as stated by [Rocky Triton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/428916/rocky-triton), [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) is another JDBC library that included Connection and Statement Pooling.

Comment: Ok, i understood... Though the answers are reversed :)